# How to zip after distnct in pySpark

Tags: pyspark

The following program fails in the zip step.

```
x = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
y = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
z = x.distinct()
print x.zip(y).collect()
```

The error that is produced depends on whether multiple partitions have been specified or not.

I understand that

> the two RDDs [must] have the same number of partitions and the same number of elements in each partition.

What is the best way to work around this restriction?

I have been performing the operation with the following code, but I am hoping to find something more efficient.

```
def safe_zip(left, right):
    ix_left = left.zipWithIndex().map(lambda row: (row[1], row[0]))
    ix_right = right.zipWithIndex().map(lambda row: (row[1], row[0]))
    return ix_left.join(ix_right).sortByKey().values()
```

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). `zip` from its Python context assumes there's an order between the iterables. For RDDs, there is no inherent ordering. However, creating keys and joining by those keys could be what you're looking for, just like you had in `safe_zip`. Mind you, the `sortByKey` operation there seems superfluous. You're likely to get better answers by explaining what you're trying to do, rather than mentioning _how_ you're doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be accomplished by using cartesian() on your RDD

```
import pyspark
x = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
y = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
x.distinct().cartesian(y.distinct()).collect()
```